# Name of an operation

Tags: vectors

If I have a vector $\vec a = [ a_1, a_2 ]$ and a vector $\vec b = [ b_1, b_2, b_3 ]$
What is the name of the operation, which produces a vector $\vec c = [ a_1b_1, a_1b_2, a_1b_3, a_2b_1, a_2b_2, a_2b_3 ]$ ?

Comment: the Kronecker product?

Comment: @KBDave Thank you sir